# Dashcode newbie: Change a button's label programmatically

Tags: javascript, button, dashcode

I'm new to Mac OS X Dashboard developement. Now, I have a button with id b_start.
When that button is clicked, I want the label of the button to change to "Round".

Now I have tried these, but none of them work:

```
document.getElementById("b_start").label = "Round";
document.getElementById("b_start").text = "Round";
document.getElementById("b_start").innerText = "Round";
document.getElementById("b_start").object.setValue("Round");
document.getElementById("b_start").value = "Round";
```

Does anyone how I can change the button's label?

Comment: Also, you are searching for the DOM element every time you set a property, that's bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the question my own. Just use this:

```
document.getElementById("b_start").object.textElement.innerText = "Round";
```

Comment: The answer provided by Bob Villa is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238523/dashcode-newbie-question-change-a-buttons-label-programmatically/1241008#1241008

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("b_start").object.setText("Round");

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("b_start").object.setEnabled(false);
```